# Latex: Change the numbering style for algorithms

Tags: algorithm, latex

My problem is that I do not know how to change the numbering style for algorithms. I have created an algoritm and its number is "Algorithm 1", but I want to have "Algorithm N.1", where N is the number of current chapter.

Let assume I have something like below

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \FOR{$i = 1$ till end}
            \STATE do something
        \ENDFOR
     \end{algorithmic}
     \label{aForLoop}
     \caption{some caption}
 \end{algorithm}
```

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: belongs at http://tex.stackexchange.com/  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page explains it quite well: https://web.archive.org/web/20100901100351/https://www.iam.ubc.ca/old_pages/newbury/tex/numbering.html

I assume this would work for algorithms as well by redefining the \thealgorithm command, in fact I read on a German forum that a user managed to disable numbering for algorithms by redefining this, so it should work.

Comment: It works for me as well, but when I use \ref{aForLoop} I got number of current subsubsection ie. 1.2.3 instead of 1.1

Answer (score 5):

This question is already 8 years old and the link in the accepted answer doesn't work anymore, so I'll post an answer here for future reference. Also, it belongs on tex.stackexchange.com.

Just add the `[chapter]` (or `[section]`) to the package declaration

```
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
```

and make sure to have a caption and a label in the algorithm, in that order:

```
\caption{The Foo Algorithm}
\label{algorithm:foo}
```

Answer (score 4):

As in the documentation:

> The numbering of algorithms can be influenced by providing the name of the document component within which numbering should be recommenced. The legal values for this option are: part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection or nothing. The default value is nothing which causes algorithms to be numbered sequentially throughout the document.

So, I think it will be enough determining the `section` value, like that:

```
\begin{algorithm}[section]
...
```

Didn't test, but should work.

Comment: It won't work for me ; /

Comment: That's \usepackage[section]{...} more likely.

Comment: This is correct except I used [algochapter]([algosection]) instead of [chapter]([section]). As the later is not working now.